# Nhibernate - query over null check on alias gives object null reference

Tags: c#, nhibernate, alias, queryover

I'm trying to make a queryover in nhibernate and i ran into a problem.

I want to recieve all of the Reports (entity in my project) that has Incidents  which has the pattern 'report', and the reports that doesnt have an incident(report can have an incident but not must - the incident is nullable)

so im trying:

```
Incident inc = null;

Session.QueryOver<Report>()
    .Left.JoinAlias(r => r.Incident, () => inc)
    .Where(new Disjunction()
        .Add(Restriction.On(() => inc).IsNull)
        .Add(() => inc.Type == "Violence"));
```

and i get:

> Object refernces not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Session.QueryOver<Report>().Left.JoinAlias(r => r.Incident, () => inc)
    .Where(
        Restrictions.Disjunction()
        .Add(Restrictions.On<Report>(r => r.Incident).IsNull)
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property(() => inc.Type), "Violence"))
    );
```